# Midi Sequencer Help

Tags: midi, daw, vst, drum, live-performance

Does anybody know if it is even possible to use my Alesis SR18 to trigger vst's in a DAW via the MIDI out feature?

Basically i'm trying to build a set up for live performance whereby once a song is selected on the SR18 and laptop the drum machine (as the master) will 'play' the pre-recorded sounds in time.

i.e. I use a footswitch as Start/Stop with the SR18 - I want this one click to play both the selected drumbeat AND send a signal to begin playback of a backing track (of sorts).

Does that even make sense to anyone? Haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible with the MIDI out!

The reference manual says the foot switch triggers the play button. My guess is that would transmit a midi message to start VST playback. It also says you can use MIDI to sync the tempo from your DAW to the drum machine.